# Load Image Before Printing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I'm generating an HTML document based on some user input and then sending it to print (as a purchase ticket). My problem is that the only image on this document is not being loaded, sometimes it works on local, but once it is on the server it never shows up, so I think that I need to load the image before sending to print the document.

Current Code I'm Using to print:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            window.print();
            window.location.assign("../")
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the window onload event `$(window).load(function() {...});`